# render Displacy Entity Recognition Visualization into Plotly Dash

Tags: html, plotly, render, spacy, plotly-dash

I want to render a piece of Entity Recognition Visualization by Spacy into a Plotly Dash app.

The html of ER Visualization for rendering is as follows:

```
<div class="entities" style="line-height: 2.5">
<mark class="entities" style="background: ...>
<span>...</span>
</mark>
<mark class="entities" style="background: ...>
<span>...</span>
</mark>
</div>
```

I have tried parsing the HTML using BeautifulSoup, and converting the HTML to Dash by the following code. But when I run **convert_html_to_dash(html_parsed)**, it is throwing *KeyError: 'style'*

```
html_parsed = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def convert_html_to_dash(el, style = None):
    if type(el) == bs.element.NavigableString:
        return str(el)
    else:
        name = el.name
        style = extract_style(el) if style is None else style
        contents = [convert_html_to_dash(x) for x in el.contents]
    return getattr(html,name.title())(contents, style=style)

def extract_style(el):
    return {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in [x.split(": ") for x in 
el.attrs["style"].split(";")]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not every tag has a `style` attribute. For tags that don't, you are attempting to access a non-existent key in the `attrs` dictionary. Python's response is a `KeyError`.

If you use `get()` instead, it will return a default value instead of raising a `KeyError`. You can specify a default value as the second argument to `get()`:

```py
return { k.strip() : v.strip() for k, v in
             [ x.split(': ') for x in el.attrs.get('style', '').split(';') ]
       }
```

Here I have chosen the empty string as the default value.

With only this change, your code still remains somewhat brittle. What if the input does not exactly match what you expect?

For one thing, there might not be a space after the colon. Changing `split(': ')` to `split(':')` will make it work even if there is no space – if there is one it will be removed anyway since you are calling `strip()` after splitting.

And what if after splitting on `';'` you receive something other than a key-value pair in the list? It is best to check if it is a valid pair (contains exactly one colon), and skip it otherwise.

Your code becomes:

```py
return { k.strip() : v.strip() for k, v in
             [ x.split(':') for x in el.attrs.get('style', '').split(';')
               if x.count(':') == 1 ] }
```

Note that I have opted for single-quotation marks. Your code uses both, but it is best to pick one and stick with it.

Comment: That is really helpful. Thanks!